# Django: Retrieving sum of amount of related objects and use it as filter

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm looking for a way to fetch the sum of an filed of an related filed inside an one-to-many-realtionship.

At the moment, If got this connection:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name of part"), max_length=255)
    # ...

class StorageItem(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
    storage = models.ForeignKey(StoragePlace)
    on_stock = models.DecimalField(_("Parts inside storage"),max_digits=10, decimal_places=4,null=True,blank=True)
    # ...

class StoragePlace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

As you can see, one part can be inside different StoragePlaces with different on_stock values. I'm looking now for a way to find all Parts, where sum of StorageItem.on_stock is below a minimal value.

For a single part I'm calculating the amount 'per foot'

```
sum_amount = 0
for si in self.storageitem_set.all():
    if si.on_stock is not None:
        sum_amount = sum_amount + si.on_stock
```

which will getting quiet inperformant when doing it form maybe 1000 Parts with a bunch of StorgeItems.

I've tried it with doing something like

```
Part.objects.annotate(total_amount=Sum('storageitem__on_stock'))
```

but failed as it appears to work only for the different direction. In fact it only returns the Part. It's returning:

```
>>> tmp = Part.objects.annotate(total_amount=Sum('storageitem__on_stock'))
>>> print tmp
[<Part: Testteil 1>]
>>> print tmp.total_amount
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'total_amount'
```

where "Testteil" is the name of the test part.

So my question is: What would be the Django way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is there an attribute/field in StoreItem caled 'amount'?

Comment: maybe `Sum('storeitem__amount')` should be `Sum('storageitem__amount')` no?

Comment: Dammid. copied the wrong example line

Comment: I'm not clear what is the problem with your `annotate` call. What is not working?

Comment: It's just not giving a result

Comment: But that is what it is supposed to do: give you a queryset of parts, each annotated with the sum which in your case is assigned to the `total_amount` attribute.

Comment: I'm afraid it's just not doing. Reupdated question

Comment: Yes, it's a *queryset*, ie a list-like container of multiple Parts. Each part in the queryset has the total_amount attribute.

Comment: But there is no list or at least I'm to stupid to access the results.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your output above clearly shows that when you do `print tmp` you get a list, containing a single Part. You can iterate over the list to access the `total_amount` of each Part, or  since you only have one part you could even just do `tmp[0].total_amount`.

Comment: As you might have seen from earlier edits, the list contains only  1 field, which is the part object. E.g. An `for i in tmp: print i` is just showing the Part. If there is somewhere total_amount hidden, I'm wonder how to access it. Neither the dictionary, the list nor the object-attribut version gave any result to me beside the original Part object I had before.